# Google App Script add row at every "N"-th row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I wanted to add 2row before every 03 Row as stated in column A. So I have written the code as below to loop and add the row.

```js
for( var i = 3; i <= row; i = i + 5 ) {
    sheet.insertRowAfter( i + count );
    count = count + 2;   
}
```

Example raw data:
[image: Example]

Expected result:
[image]

Problem now:
the google sheets total data:18652 rows, the execution time is longer than I expected. Is there any method/way to increase the speed of execution？

Error:
[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `I wanted to add 2row before every 03 Row as stated in column A.` and your sample image. Can I ask you about the detail of your goal?

Comment: Hii sirs, sry i din explain well. I have added expected result wanted

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to achieve the situations like the images shown in your question.
- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about using Sheets API? I thought that when Sheets API is used for your situation, the process cost will be able to be reduced a little. When Sheets API is used for your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"); // Please set the sheet name

  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const requests = [];
  for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i += 5) {
    requests.push({ insertDimension: { range: { sheetId, dimension: "ROWS", startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 2 } } });
  }
  requests.reverse();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate)
- [InsertDimensionRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#insertdimensionrequest)

### Added:

About `V8 runtime is enable, still it doesn't work.`, when I saw your current script, your script is as follows.

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zsnqh6kNbeOJiDTh5olFj432Hkx5OPkynI1NGAO8pBk");
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Forecast1");
  
 
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const requestor = [];
 for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i += 5) {
    requestor.push({insertDimension: { range: { sheetId: ss.getId(), dimension: "ROWS", startIndex: 1, endIndex: 1 + 2 } } });
    
  }
  requestor.reverse();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({requests:requestor},  ss.getId());

}
```

1. Unfortunately, I could confirm that you didn't correctly reflect my proposed script.
2. This script is different from the script shown in your sample image.
3. I had already mentioned this issue in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70675598/google-app-script-add-row-at-every-n-th-row/70678166?noredirect=1#comment124994053_70678166).

   > From your error message, I think that you might not correctly reflect my proposed script. Because in your error, when the Spreadsheet ID is used as the sheet ID, such an error occurs.
4. I proposed `requests.push({ insertDimension: { range: { sheetId, dimension: "ROWS", startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 2 } } });` in the loop. But you had modified to `requestor.push({ insertDimension: { range: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(), dimension: "ROWS", startIndex: 1, endIndex: 1 + 2 } } });`. This is not correctly reflect my proposed script.

#### Modified script:

When your current script is modified using your `const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zsnqh6kNbeOJiDTh5olFj432Hkx5OPkynI1NGAO8pBk")`, it becomes as follows. Please test this script by not modifying.

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1zsnqh6kNbeOJiDTh5olFj432Hkx5OPkynI1NGAO8pBk");

  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("testing"); // Please set the sheet name

  const sheetId = sheet.getSheetId();
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
  const requests = [];
  for (var i = 3; i <= lastRow; i += 5) {
    requests.push({ insertDimension: { range: { sheetId, dimension: "ROWS", startIndex: i, endIndex: i + 2 } } });
  }
  requests.reverse();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate({ requests }, ss.getId());
}
```

#### Note:

- Your sheet of "Forecast1" is large (18732 rows and 59 columns). So, first, in order to test this script, I would like to recommend using your sample sheet of "testing" and confirm whether the script works.
- When I tested your sample sheet of "testing", no error occurs. But, when I tested your "Forecast1", an error related to the internal error of Sheets API. I'm worried that this might be related to the current limitation (not shown). From this, about the large sheet, for example, when you tested my script for "Forecast1", the same issue occurs, I would like to recommend splitting the sheet for reducing the size.

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Your answer should be best sample for me. Unfortunately I facing error "API call to sheets.spreadsheets.batchUpdate failed with error: Invalid value at 'requests[0].insert_dimension.range.sheet_id' (TYPE_INT32), "1zsnqh6kNbeOJiDTh5olFj432Hkx5OPkynI1NGAO8pBk""

Comment: @Ah Chuan Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. From your error message, I think that you might not correctly reflect my proposed script. Because in your error, when the Spreadsheet ID is used as the sheet ID, such an error occurs. First, I would like to recommend testing using my original script. If you cannot understand this, please provide your current whole script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to check it.

Comment: Thanks Tanaike. I also face the issue when i using your original script. I have share the error message on my post. Appreciate if you could help.

Comment: @Ah Chuan Thank you for replying and adding the information. In that case, I'm worried that you might not enable V8 runtime. Because when V8 runtime is not used, such error occurs. Could you please confirm it again? If V8 runtime is not used, please enable it and test it again. I deeply apologize that my proposed script used V8 runtime. If you are required to disable V8 runtime, please tell me.

Comment: V8 runtime is enable, still it doesn't work. Appreciate if you could access debug on my script. "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zsnqh6kNbeOJiDTh5olFj432Hkx5OPkynI1NGAO8pBk/edit?usp=sharing"

Comment: @Ah Chuan Thank you for replying and providing your sample Spreadsheet. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your provided sample, I confirmed that you didn't correctly reflect my proposed script. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. For your sample script, I added the modified script. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: @Ah Chuan And, it seems that from your current script in your sample Spreadsheet, you don't correctly reflect my proposed script. So I'm worried that you might not be able to understand my English. If you cannot understand my English, please tell me.